# how to get the file name and show on list

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app to transfer and receive file using the flashlight and the camera.
Now I am trying to choose file and display its name in the send fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    browse = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.browse);

    browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseFile;
            Intent intent;
            chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.setType("file/*");
            intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String uriString = uri.toString();
                File myFile = new File(uriString);
                String displayName = null;
                if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    displayName = myFile.getName();
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How can I display the name of selected files in list?
And later on, how can I send the selected file?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) before posting a question. File has a methods for getting name, path etc. . What you need is `file.getName()` . But you should first check if file exists, `if(file.exists()) then {....}`